# How to redirect non-existent .html files to mvc3 routes?

Tags: seo, iis-7.5, url-routing

This is probably a duplicate, but my Google-foo is off or something, because I cannot find the answer to this simple question.

I have moved an old site to MVC3 on IIS7.5 and I need to redirect some old .html extension urls to new MVC Controller Actions.

I added URL mappings.

```
<urlMappings>
    <!-- Doesn't work -->
    <add url="~/OldUrl.html" mappedUrl="~/NewController"/> 
    <!-- Works but is rewrite instead of redirect -->
    <add url="~/OldUrl.aspx" mappedUrl="~/NewController"/> 
</urlMappings>
```

The above is not working for 2 reasons.  First, the .html extension doesn't get re-mapped and second, the .aspx extension gets re-mapped rather than rewritten.

I tried to add the StaticFileHandler because I thought maybe the .HTML extension was being ignored by .NET but in fact that handler was already there.

I don't have access to IIS Management Tools because it is in shared hosting, but I should be able to just add something to the web.config to get these to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
<system.webServer>
  <!-- The RewriteModule may need to be added if it isn't 
       already included in machine.config or application.config
  <modules>
      <add name="RewriteModule" />
  </modules>
  -->
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect1">
              <match url="^OldUrl.html$" />
              <action type="Redirect" 
                      url="/NewController" 
                      redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Redirect2">
              <match url="^OldUrl.aspx$" />
              <action type="Redirect" 
                      url="/NewController" 
                      redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```